# Adding Condition to CMake add_definitions() command

Tags: cmake

I have two targets for my CMake file. After I run **cmake ..** , I can either say **make rsutest** for unit tests and build a test executable or say **make rsu** to get a normal executable. If I am building my test target I want to add a define to the test code with **add_definitions(-DRSU_TEST)** command so that some of the lines in the actual code can be ignored  . How can I write my CMake file so **#define RSU_TEST** line is only active when I build the test target ?

```
add_custom_target(rsutest COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} DEPENDS rsu_test)
add_custom_target(rsu COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} DEPENDS rsu_agent)

if(rsutest)  // this if else statement doesn't work and I need a a condition  
add_definitions(-DRSU_TEST)// which will only be true when I build rsutest
endif(rsutest)
```

Comment: `add_target_definitions()`?

Comment: are you sure that command exists ?

Comment: Oops, it is `target_compile_definitions()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
option(WITH_TEST "BUILD THE TEST CODE" OFF)

if(WITH_TEST)

add_definitions(-DRSU_TEST)

endif()
```

Then if I want to run the test code I use **cmake .. -DWITH_TEST=ON** instead of just cmake ... And turn it off by **cmake .. -DWITH_TEST=OFF** when I want my normal build.